# Mongoose aggregation expressions within the query language

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am looking for a way to use aggregation expressions within the query language.

e.g this is my aggregation

```
Locations.aggregate([
{ "$match": { "name": "development" } },
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "users",
        "localField": "followers",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "followers"
    }
}
])
```

How can we turn it into a `find`

like

```
Locations.find( ...aggregation goes here )
```

PS: I've researched on **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** but there's nowhere it shows how to add the `$lookup` or `$match` into it.

Comment: Mongoose provides the *aggregate* method to do aggregation queries

Comment: @ArielAlvarado is it possible to do aggregations in the query instead of the actual aggregation method?

Comment: Why would you want to turn an aggregate query to a find one?

Comment: @chridam i know it's quite redundant, but am in a situation that requires it, am trying to see whether this is possible, do you think it's possible?